# Can't call library function in user defined function

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, c-strings, string-comparison

I am making a user defined function of strcmp() in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int la,lb;    // la and lb for length of 2 strings
 
int scompare(char [],char []);

int main() {

 char a[50],b[50];     // a and b are 2 strings

printf("Enter 2 strings \n");
gets(a);
gets(b);
la =strlen(a);
lb =strlen(b);
printf("%d",scompare(a,b));

 }
 int scompare(char a[la],char b[lb])
   {
     for(int i=0 ;i<max(la,lb);i++)
     { // loop for comparing characters of 2 strings

       // here in vs code it is showing error --->
       // warning: implicit declaration of function 'max' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

for(int i=0 ;i<max(la,lb);i++)

         int k = a[i]-b[i];// k is the sum of ascii of characters of a and b
   
         if(k!=0 &&toupper(a[i])==toupper(b[i]))
         return (k>0)?1:-1;

         // other error is showing here in function toupper --->  warning: implicit declaration of function 'toupper' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

if(k!=0 &&toupper(a[i])==toupper(b[i])) 

         else if(k!=0)
        return k;
    
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: "int k = a[i]-b[i];
k is the sum of ascii of characters of a and b" - are you sure?:)

Comment: Also, [you shouldn't be using the `gets` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10871073).

Comment: The code when `k` is non-zero but the characters are the same except for case is dubious; the return of `(k>0)?1:-1` is not much different from `return k`—if it is being used merely to indicate ordering. Is `scompare` supposed to do a case-insensitive comparison? What is it supposed to do? What is the purpose of `if(k!=0 &&toupper(a[i])==toupper(b[i]))
         return (k>0)?1:-1;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling a function you need to provide its declaration that can be present for example in a header.

There is no standard function `max` in C. You need to write such a function yourself.

To use the standard function `toupper` you need to include the header `<ctype.h>`

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

This loop (if to assume that the function `max` is defined somewhere)

```
for(int i=0 ;i<max(la,lb);i++)
```

can invoke undefined behavior then lengths of strings are not equal to each other.

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is not a standard C function. It is unsafe. You should use `fgets`.

And this function declaration

```
int scompare(char a[la],char b[lb]);
```

does not make a sense.

The function should be declared like

```
int scompare( const char a[], const char b[] );
```

Comment: Re “And this function declaration `int scompare(char a[la],char b[lb]);` does not make a sense”: That declares `scompare` to be a function that returns an `int` and takes parameters `a` and `b` that are arrays of `char` with `la` and `lb` elements, respectively. `la` and `lb` were declared earlier.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And what? What is the sense of using la and lb in the function declaration?

Comment: It conveys to the reader how long the arrays are expected to be.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are wrong. This has nothing common with lengths of arrays. It only makes the function declaration dependent on global variables.

Comment: It is routine to declare array parameters in functions with all their dimensions even if the first dimension is ignored by the compiler, as a way of documenting the expected array length. The function is in fact dependent on global variables regardless of whether they are used in the parameters or not, because they are used in the code inside the function. That is bad design, but that is the way it is, and the meaning of the parameter declarations as shown in the question is clear.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The user of the function sees its declaration before main without la and lb. These statements la =strlen(a);
lb =strlen(b); should be placed inside the function instead of declaring parameters with la and lb.

Comment: Yes, the function should be defined differently. That is unrelated to the fact that declaring array parameters with dimensions is routine (ordinary), conforming C, well-defined, and clear.

Comment: Given that you are critiquing OP’s code beyond what was asked in the question, you missed an actual problem that could cause the program to misbehave: `toupper(a[i])` should be `toupper((unsigned char) a[i])`, and similarly for `toupper(b[i])`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is unclear because reading the function definition the user does not know how la and lb are obtained that is whether they are sizes of arrays or lengths of strings.

Comment: Judging from the code, they are lengths of arrays, as the code uses `i<max(la,lb)` as a termination condition and never checks for a null character. So it is a mistake to recommend using `strlen(a)` or `strlen(b)` inside the function, as nothing in the code inside the function (`main` does use `strlen`) indicates the caller wishes to check the strings up to a null terminator rather than to lengths `la` and `lb`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, max and toupper are not defined in any headers.
I think it must be like bellow.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

int la, lb;

int scompare(char [], char []);

int main()
{
    char a[50], b[50];

    printf("Enter 2 strings \n");
    gets(a);
    gets(b);

    la = strlen(a);
    lb = strlen(b);
    printf("%d\n", scompare(a, b));
}

int scompare(char a[], char b[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max(la, lb); i++)
    {
        int k = a[i] - b[i];
        if (k && toupper(a[i]) == toupper(b[i]))
        {
            return (k > 0 ? 1 : -1);
        }
        else if (k)
        {
            return k;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now it will be built successfully, and result is
[image]

But, I think that your scompare function is not efficient.
In my opinion

```
int scompare(char a[], char b[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max(la, lb); i++)
    {
        int k = a[i] - b[i];
        if (k == 0) continue;

        return k > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use functions from other libraries, you need to include these libraries:

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

if(k!=0 &&toupper(a[i])==toupper(b[i]))
         return (k>0)?1:-1;
...
```

If you use your own function, you need to declare it before usage and define it in the same file. Lets assume that `int max(int, int)` is your function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
int max(int lhs, int rhs);

...

/* usage */
int scompare(char a[la],char b[lb])
   {
     for(int i=0 ;i<max(la,lb);i++)
     {

...

/* definition */
int max(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
```